# How to assign taxonomy term TID to field collections term reference field programmatically?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a field_collection field attached to user profiles.  This is an "unlimited" field, so, the user can add as many addresses as they like via their profile page.  However, I also need to add addresses to their profile programmatically from elsewhere (in a module).  I have the following code:

```
    function _cnm_address_add_user_address($address=array()) {
      //Load the controller class file.
      module_load_include('inc', 'entity', 'includes/entity.controller');

        $values = array();
      $user = user_uid_optional_load();
      if(is_object($user)){
        //Get any previously saved field values to make sure they are not overwritten
        //while we attempt to save the new one
        $count = 0;    
        if(!empty($user->field_cnm_address['und'][0]['value'])){
          foreach($user->field_cnm_address['und'] as $fc){
            $fc_obj = field_collection_item_load($fc['value']);
            //If any exiting field values are empty, default to empty string ''
            $fname = (!empty($fc_obj->field_cnm_address_fname['und'][0]['value']))
                ? $fc_obj->field_cnm_address_fname['und'][0]['value'] : '';
            $lname = (!empty($fc_obj->field_cnm_address_lname['und'][0]['value']))
                ? $fc_obj->field_cnm_address_lname['und'][0]['value'] : '';
            $country_tid = (!empty($fc_obj->field_cnm_address_country['und'][0]['tid']))
                ? $fc_obj->field_cnm_address_country['und'][0]['tid'] : 0;
            $state_tid = (!empty($fc_obj->field_cnm_address_state['und'][0]['tid']))
                ? $fc_obj->field_cnm_address_state['und'][0]['tid'] : 0;
            //Add fields to $values array
                  $values[$count] = array(
                    'field_cnm_address_fname' => array('und' => array(array('value' => $fname)),),
                    'field_cnm_address_lname' => array('und' => array(array('value' => $lname)),),
                    'field_cnm_address_country' => array('und' => array(array('tid' => $country_tid)),),
                    'field_cnm_address_state' => array('und' => array(array('tid' => $state_tid)),),
                  );
                  //Set the field_collection field_name for this set of fields
                  $values[$count]['field_name'] = 'field_cnm_address';
                  $count++;
          }
        }

            //The new entry...
          $values[$count] = array(
            'field_cnm_address_fname' => array('und' => array(array('value' => $address['fname'])),),
            'field_cnm_address_lname' => array('und' => array(array('value' => $address['lname'])),),
            'field_cnm_address_country' => array('und' => array(array('tid' => $address['country'])),),
            'field_cnm_address_state' => array('und' => array(array('tid' => $address['state'])),),
          );
          //Set the field_collection field_name for this new entry
            $values[$count]['field_name'] = 'field_cnm_address';

        //Save all values
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                $field_entity = entity_create('field_collection_item', $value);
                $field_entity->setHostEntity('user', $user);
                $field_entity->save();
            }       
        }
    }
```

Here is my problem: There doesn't seem to be any issue with adding regular string values (such as the first name field, which uses ['und'][0]['value']), however, my country and state fields are *term reference fields* and when I try to add the tid by using ['und'][0]['tid'] (which is the format that the field collection uses itself -- see how I retrieved previous values from the fields), I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in taxonomy_term_save() (line 628 of /.../modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vid in taxonomy_term_save() (line 630 of /.../modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 175 of /.../includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 354 of /.../includes/entity.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in taxonomy_term_save() (line 631 of /.../modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7818 of /.../includes/common.inc).
```

It appears to be trying to save a new taxonomy term!?  However, that is NOT what I want.  Instead, I am trying to assign an existing taxonomy term *tid* to the field within a field_collection, *not* save a new term object.

Any ideas?